# Swift Data Model returning nil after unwrapping when there clearly is value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I'm currently trying to parse data in a data "struct/model"

**Code for data model:**

```
import Foundation
struct DataModel {
    //MARK: Organizes data structs

    let userId: String
    let Time: String
    let Restaurant: String
    let PartySize: String
    let date: String

}
```

I put data into it and then try and fit that data back into a reusable cell for a table view

**Code for Reusable cell:**

```
class RegistrationCell: UITableViewCell {

    //SetUp xib File
    @IBOutlet weak var PSize: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Time: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Date: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Email: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Resto: UILabel!

}
```

Once I try and put the data from the data model into the cell I get "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"

**Error Image:**
[image: Error Image]

**Full Code:**

```
//  ReservationsViewController.swift
//  MySeat
//
//  Created by Adam Abu Ghaida on 3/16/20.
//  Copyright © 2020 Adam Abu Ghaida. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class ReservationsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var ReservationTableView: UITableView!

    let DB = Database.database().reference().child("Reservations")

    //var dataArray: [[String]] = []
    var dataArray: [DataModel] = []


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ReservationTableView.dataSource = self

        ReservationTableView.register(RegistrationCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        LoadData()


    }

    func LoadData(){


        DB.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in


            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String,String>

            let PSize = snapshotValue["PartySize"]!
            let Resto = snapshotValue["Restaurant"]!
            let UID = snapshotValue["Uid"]!
            let Time = snapshotValue["Time"]!
            let Date = snapshotValue["date"]!

            let DBData = DataModel(userId:UID, Time: Time, Restaurant: Resto, PartySize: Resto, date: Date)



            //self.dataArray.append(InfoArray)
            self.dataArray.append(DBData)
            print(self.dataArray)

            self.configTabelView()
            self.ReservationTableView.reloadData()



        }

    }

    func configTabelView() {
        ReservationTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}



extension ReservationsViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let data = dataArray[indexPath.row]

        let cell = ReservationTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! RegistrationCell

        print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\(data)\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n")

        cell.Email.text = data.userId
        cell.PSize.text = data.PartySize
        cell.Resto.text = data.Restaurant
        cell.Date.text = data.date
        cell.Time.text = data.Time

        return cell
    }
}
```

These same errors also happen with all other "cell.xxx.text" statements

**EDIT:**

Managed to fix this issue, simply take the `self.ReservationTableView.reloadData()` outside the closure.

Another problem: The cells don't show up now...

Comment: Quick Note: this same error happens with all the other "cell.xxx.text" statements

Comment: Please add additional info in your question, not in the comments. See also [ask].

Comment: The error could also occur when `cell.Email`, etc  is `nil`.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the suggestion,
I checked the cell and it all contains values

Comment: What is line 84 in your ReservationsViewController? That's where the error occurs.

Comment: Line 84 is where I set up the cell's Email label.

Comment: If the crash occurs in this line then the outlets in the custom cell are not connected (the label `Email` is `nil`).

Comment: Have you check that your cell is successfully created with your RegistrationCell?

Comment: @koen, I saw your comment on asynchronous data and it worked amazingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you designed your cell as a Prototype in Storyboard, remove this line:

```
ReservationTableView.register(RegistrationCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

If you designed it as a xib file, you need to replace that line with something close to this:

```
ReservationTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "RegistrationCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

As a side note... when getting that type of error where you are *convinced* the value should be there, check the rest of the line.

For example, if you do this:

```
cell.Email.text = "this is a test"
```

you will almost certainly get the same error message. At that point, you know it is *not* your data object.

Comment: I did try this, but it showed nothing on the table view post-build

Comment: Is your cell designed in a xib file or storyboard prototype?

Comment: my cell is designed in a Xib file

Comment: So you used the `.register(UINib(nibName:...` format and you no longer get the error but you don't see anything in the cells?

Comment: Exactly, I might be missing something with the nib file or sorts...

Comment: Make sure in your xib, the ***cell*** is assigned to your custom class, and not **File's Owner** (if it was the other way around, you'll want to delete and re-connect the outlets)

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding... I checked the class of the nib and it is connected to RegistrationCell

Comment: Is your cell class in your xib assigned like this: https://imgur.com/a/KIWF71O

Comment: Yes, the cell is assigned like that.

Comment: hmm... use the register nib format, and change your label `.text =` lines to `= "A"`, `= "B"`, etc... Assuming you don't get the same "unwrapping" error, see if those letters show up. If they don't use Debug View Hierarchy to inspect your cells to see where the labels are (it can also help to give your labels contrasting background colors so it's easy to see their frames at run-time).

Comment: I've had many problems in my coding journey, and this is the only one left me stumped this bad... I have 0 clue about why things are going wrong, and I've compared my code to other working projects, I think I'm going to take a breather.